# Name the sihabi whose four generation are sihabih?

Tags: sahaba

There are thousands of sihabi whom predecessor and successors are sihabi but is there any sihabi whos maximum generation are sihabi ?

Comment: Abu Bakr's parents, children, grandchildren were Sahabah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best and noblest companion of Hazrat Mohammad (s.a.w) "hazrat abu bakr(r.a)"
His(r.a) proper and real name was Abdullah or Abul-Kaaba and "Abu Bakr" was his kunya 
whose parents,children and lineage(grand-children/progency) were sahaaba.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_tree_of_Abu_Bakr

Answer (score 0):

Abdullah ibn zubair son of Asma bint Abu Bakr bin Abu Quhafa

Answer (score -1):

Abdul rehman ibn abi bakar and his son hazrat abu bakar siddique and his son hazrat ali and his son hazrat imam hussain and hassan

Comment: This could profit from some evidences supporting your claims. See [answer].